# Command line for detecting monitors, instead of relogging

Tags: ubuntu, multi-monitor

If I plug monitors to my laptop, `arandr` doesn't see them.
It's as if they were not plugged.

On the contrary, if I relog (log out, log in) with monitors plugged, then I will be able two manage the additional screens correctly with `arandr`

Is there a command line I could launch, that would detect the monitors, without my needing to relog my session ?

My distro is ubuntu, and I use fluxbox as Window Manager. But I don't think it is related.

Comment: Do you have an NVidia card on that laptop?

Comment: No, it is an intel graphic card: `~$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 0a2e (rev 09)`